# Is the method Collectors.toList() thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading the book "Mastering Lambdas: Java Programming in a Multicore World".
It has simple example of collecting stream of books to list :

```
List<Book> bookList = libraryStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And I quote from the book:

> the stream operations can be safely executed in parallel, even if the List into which the stream elements are accumulated (ArrayList is used in the current implementation) is not threadsafe.

I don't understand how it can be thread safe after the returned list it modified from multiple thread if collecting using parallel stream.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350288/parallel-streams-collectors-and-thread-safety: Brian Goetz, Java Language Architect provides a good answer

Comment: The list is not modified from different threads. Several lists are created instead and they are finally merged together.

Comment: The _result_ can't be thread-safely modified, but `Collections.toList()` internally does the right thing even if it's working in parallel.

Comment: During reduce operation in parallel, the stream is split and then merged. So yes it can work in parallel without side affects.