# Initial capacity for CopyOnWriteArrayList

Tags: java

Many List implementations have an option to specify an initial capacity for the collection, why is this not allowed for [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)?

Comment: Why do you think you would need one?

Comment: I know the operations are expensive because it gives a fresh copy every time, but hadn't closely looked at the constructor before. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39453595/2063026) got me thinking that this is not even possible. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is an extremely poor choice to be used in a parallel stream operating on a large collection

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a conventional `ArrayList` the capacity is a hint to reserve more space in the backing array for more elements to be added to the list later on.

In a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, every (atomic) write operation creates a new backing array.  There is no point in preallocating an array that is bigger than the current list size because that space would never be used.

Comment: Thanks, that generally makes sense. I was hoping to achieve some performance gains by allocating a bigger capacity when working with large collections. Clearly, this would be a wrong choice of data structure to use (for frequent writes)

Comment: *Clearly, this would be a wrong choice of data structure to use (for frequent writes)* -- Absolutely correct!